# How do I find all the user's average score without SELECT AVG()

Tags: mysql

I want to get the avg score for each user and output all the userid that has avg over 85. But I only want my results to have userid. I know how to find average if I SELECT AVG()... but in this case I don't know what to do...

This is actually for SQL++ Primer but I think it works like MYSQL mostly.

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM Users u, Observe o
WHERE u.id = o.u_id
AND o.kind = "a"
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING AVG(o.rate) > 85;
```

expected to have results like id:2, id:3 ...
and each id has multiple rates

Comment: Please use `JOIN` instead of use `,` comma, `JOIN` is ANSI syntax which you should use.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Seems ok other than for some reason you don't want to use average, but why would you do that?